# Difference between ADUM6403 and ADUM6403ARIZ?

Tags: surface-mount

I bought ADUM6403ARIZ and I am thinking how it might fit ADUM6403. 
I am thinking the differences between the two chips

- ADUM6403
- ADUM6403ARIZ

ADUM6400ARIZ should be equivalent to ADUM6403, but not sure how equivalent is ADUM6403 to ADUM6403ARIZ. 
Manual [here](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM6400_6401_6402_6403_6404.pdf).
There are also other endings CRIZ, CRWZ, ARWZ, ... about which I am not sure.

---

Can you use ADUM6403ARIZ in the place of ADUM6403?

Comment: What does the holy **datasheet** say about it ? It not a manual, it's a datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on the 2nd to the last page of the data sheet - it tells you what the package options are. You have two types basically - one is a wider body than the other.

Any device you choose MUST have the letters following the base part number hence ADUM6403 is not a valid full part number for the device. The options you have are: -

- ARWZ
- CRWZ
- ARIZ
- CRIZ

Read the data sheet on the 2nd to last page to understand what they mean.